# Calling extension methods inside extension method class or not?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Inside extension methods it sometimes makes sense to use other extension methods. I cannot make up my mind if you should use *"this"* syntax or not.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    // Foo vs Foo1
    public static string Foo(this string s)
    {
        return s + "Foo" + s.Bar(); // "this" syntax
    }

    public static string Foo1(this string s)
    {
        return s + "Foo" + Bar(s);
    }

    public static string Bar(this string s)
    {
        return s + "Bar";
    }
}
```

`Foo` vs `Foo1`. Two questions arise:

1. Performance. Is there any difference in terms of generated `IL` code?
2. Code Design. Which one of the two approaches would be preferable? Why?

Comment: Personally i prefere extension methods. But those are just syntactical sugar. Foo and Foo1 will be compiled the exact same way. Therefor there is no difference in performance. Edit: A benefit of using extension methods is the support of IntelliSense. You can type your variable's name and IntelliSense will also show you the extension methods. You can explore frameworks much faster with this approach (like Linq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no perfomance difference, because extension methods are compiled into regular static method calls.
2. I'd say `this` syntax is preferrable, because if you have method declared as extension method (`this string s`) - it is good to *always* call it as extension method and not mix up with regular static calls.

Comment: Seems like a good convention.